# Why won't this mysql query work?

Tags: mysql, rowcount

I have this query:

```
$q = $dbc -> prepare("SELECT * FROM mailbox WHERE msgTo = ? && read = 0");
$q -> execute(array($user['id']));
$mailboxCount = $q -> rowCount();
```

Now in my table I have

```
msgTo = 1, read = 0
```

$user['id'] is equal to **1**

But the row count returns 0 why is this?

Comment: rowCount is not guaranteed to work with select.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from [`Manual`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php)

> **PDOStatement->rowCount** — Returns the number of rows affected by the
>   last SQL statement
>
> PDOStatement::rowCount() returns the number of rows affected by the
>   last **DELETE, INSERT, or UPDATE** statement executed by the corresponding
>   PDOStatement object.

SEE this [`example`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php#example-992) and written clearly

> For most databases, PDOStatement::rowCount() does not return the
>   number of rows affected by a SELECT statement. Instead, use
>   PDO::query() to issue a SELECT COUNT(*) statement with the same
>   predicates as your intended SELECT statement, then use
>   PDOStatement::fetchColumn() to retrieve the number of rows that will
>   be returned.

Comment: Please see the example and read Manual. best lesson is learnt by youself. :)

Comment: I have other SELECT statements with rowcount and they execute successfully? why is this?

Answer (score 1):

IMHO rowCount() only matches on UPDATE and DELETE statements and not on SELECT queries. By selecting * you fetch all data from the database. Since you only want the number of rows, use the count()-function instead - that is much more efficient.

```
SELECT count(*) FROM mailbox WHERE msgTo = ? && read = 0
```

Comment: The change was using the COUNT function instead of selecting all of the rows and counting them.  If you're not actually using the data, and you just want to know how many rows, a count is much more efficient than actually pulling all of the data.

Comment: How do I get the count variable out of the query?

Comment: @Dan Bizdadea it is better though, I should be using this, it is more efficient

Comment: I agree with even better part :) I was gonna downvote Erik's post, but than i sow the count(*) and reconsidered. But still, he's missing the point about why your function returns 0